# Problem creating customer account stripe nodejs

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm having trouble creating a stripe client account in node.

ALL CODE:

```
 const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
  email: emailAddress,
  description: uid,
  name: name_lastname,
  address: {city: "Warszawa",
      country: "Poland",
      line1: "Testowa",
      line2: "22",
      postal_code: "00-001",
      state: "mazowieckie"
    },
  source: token,
  tax: {
        location: {
          source: 'billing_address',
        },
     },
});
```

If I add tax: {} to stripe.customers.create:

```
  tax: {
        location: {
          source: 'billing_address',
        },
     },
```

the customer's account is not created, if I delete it and the code looks like this, everything works fine:

```
 const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
  email: emailAddress,
  description: uid,
  name: name_lastname,
  address: {city: "Warszawa",
      country: "Poland",
      line1: "Testowa",
      line2: "22",
      postal_code: "00-001",
      state: "mazowieckie"
    },
  source: token,
});
```

I used this link: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object?lang=node

I just want to give the client the appropriate TAX rate when creating the client, so that it will add taxrate automatically based on the given country in the billing address.

Comment: Do the trailing commas on final parameters cause an issue? e.g. source: 'billing_address',

Comment: No, it wasn't a problem. Bad value added in Tax was a problem - see RyanM's answer

Comment: For future users: In billing address, the country should have 2 letters instead of the whole name, otherwise it will not be added correctly and automatic VAT rate will not be possible. Instead of Poland, it should be PL :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at doc specific to the [Create Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create?lang=node) API request you'll see that the only `customer.tax` attribute you can add is `ip_address`.

Additionally taxes will not automatically get added unless you are using some other tool or integration to handle that.  [Stripe Tax](https://stripe.com/docs/tax) is an option there but it doesn't cover all use cases.

In general the address parameter should be fine fo most use cases.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice it and used the Customer object. If I would like to return a tax from a customer, it is possible using the billing address, however, it will not be possible to set it during creation. So I did so that I added automatic_tax when creating the subscription and it worked. Now, when creating a subscription, tax is added based on the customer's address.